# Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY Equivalent in Hibernate 5 CriteriaQuery?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria

Before Hibernate 5 it was possible to use DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY field to ensures that each row of results is a distinct instance of the root entity. Example:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

But in Hibernate 5 CriteriaQuery it's not possible to use it like this. Is there any replacement for that?

Now I am using distinct() method in Hibernate 5:

```
criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
```

Does it provide the same behaviour? If it doesn't what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate deprecated `setResultTransformer` without providing a different way - see https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-resulttransformer-is-deprecated-what-to-use-instead/232/5

So, if you need to use `setResultTransformer` you need to use hibernate `Query` until hibernate provides a replacement.

Comment: I don't want to use setResultTransformer. I just want the same behaviour of DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY -> (ensures that each row of results is a distinct instance of the root entity) with criteriaQuery. Is it possible?

Comment: @H.Ç.T Do you have an example where you are getting a duplicate?  DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY is only required when there is a joined one to many table.